# mongo - $inc incrementing by 2 instead of 1 using meteor methods

Tags: mongodb, meteor

**Meteor Method:-**

```
incrementCount: function(toPerson){

Meteor.users.update({'emails.0.address': toPerson}, {$inc: {'profile.notificationCount': 1}});

}
```

**Meteor Method Call:-**

```
Meteor.call("incrementCount", message.to);
```

The issue is on first load the notificationCount increments by 2,
however the loads afterwards increment accurately by 1.

I have searched the docs for MongoDB for solutions but did not have any success.

Thank you in advance for any responses.

Comment: This should not normally happen. Is there any chance that any method calls failed? Meteor re-tries failed method calls, so this could be the case. Try restarting the server and refresh the client and see if this happens again.

Comment: I have restarted the server and refreshed the pages but still the problem persists.

Comment: I would start by logging calls to console. This will tell you if you are calling it twice by mistake, for some reason (which is likely the case). If so, find out why this happens.

Comment: I'll look into it once again, thanks by the way. Hope it works out.

Comment: Problem resolved, thank you MasterAM, a different meteor method was also being called implementing the same function, that was why it was incrementing by 2.

Comment: I know it was ridiculous, but was on it for more than a day now.

Comment: Arun, I have problems like this all the time - don't feel bad.  Consider adding your own answer?